# MS Access default value in expression?

Tags: ms-access, expression

I have two queries.

One has a list of tasks aggregated out from a table.

One is a "GROUP BY" query that groups billed hours by task from a timesheet.

I am writing a query to assign the hours to the tasks.

This is an expression I am using to select out certain hours for a column for use in reporting:

```
CumulativeEngineeringBurn: 
IIf(
  IIf([EngOrDrf]="ENG",[qry_MappedHours_aggregate].[SumOfMapped_Hours],0)
  Is Null,0,
  IIf([EngOrDrf]="ENG",[qry_MappedHours_aggregate].[SumOfMapped_Hours],0)
)
```

I am using the IIf to try and make sure that I don't get any empty fields but I am still getting some blanks. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Please show us both the queries as well, as at the moment we have nothing to refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved much easier with the nz() function. What you want is:
`nz(IIf([EngOrDrf]="ENG",[qry_MappedHours_aggregate].[SumOfMapped_Hours],0),0)`
or even better:
`IIf([EngOrDrf]="ENG",nz([qry_MappedHours_aggregate].[SumOfMapped_Hours],0),0)`

Comment: after using the NZ function I can't seem to link the query to an excel spreadsheet anymore? i found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595374/need-help-in-vba-excel-and-sql-query so that means I need to go back to my double iif(iif())?

Answer (score 0):

I remade the query again.

The expression is the same but for whatever reason it works now as intended now.

As far as I can tell everything is the same so I am not sure what the problem is.